# How to keep Vim's visual mode selection while scrolling with Ctrl-F?

Tags: vim, gvim

When I select text in Vim's visual mode, scrolling with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> cancels the selection. How can I keep the selection while scrolling (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>)?

Comment: When I press Ctrl+f in visual mode, it doesn't cancel the selection. It continues to select additional lines.  Your plugin might have changed default settings. Try starting vim with vim -u NONE filename. It should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens on Windows with the default configuration, which calls [`:behave mswin`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html#:behave), which in turn sets

```
keymodel=startsel,stopsel
```

The [`stopsel`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27keymodel%27) tells Vim to stop the selection if the cursor keys, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, <kbd>PageDown</kbd> are pressed. For some reason <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> seems to trigger <kbd>PageDown</kbd>.

To change this behavior, you can remove `stopsel` from the `keymodel` setting:

```
:e $HOME/_gvimrc
```

and add the following:

```
" Prevent CTRL-F to abort the selection (in visual mode)
" This is caused by $VIM/_vimrc ':behave mswin' which sets 'keymodel' to
" include 'stopsel' which means that non-shifted special keys stop selection.
set keymodel=startsel
```

## References

- vim mailing list posting: ['Behave mswin, visual mode, and <C-F>'](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vim_use/keymodel/vim_use/MTmvH5OCJek/bqX8bUowVMwJ).